# fill div with dynamic images and no gaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Potomaks Instagram Jquery script to pull images for a certain tag. I have the CSS set to auto-resize the images so that the row will fit across the entire table.

The table is set at 100%, the main div for images set at 100%.

But for some reason, there is a GAP at the end no matter what I do. I have thoroughly checked the code and there is no explanation. I suspect its *possibly* related to float:left OR its related to the javascript.

Eitherway, my goal is to have images fill the entire table at 20% images widths' (5 images each row).

As it is now, whether the images are 10%, 15%, 20%, there is a gap at the right

http://postimg.org/image/rkz5zxtfr/

My html is as follows:

```
  <script src="jquery.instagram.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jgram.css"  type="text/css" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 var tokeny= "xxxx";
 var ids= tokeny.substr(0, tokeny.indexOf('.')); 
 var
   insta_container = $(".instagram")
    ,  insta_next_url

  insta_container.instagram({
  hash: 'motorcycles'
, clientId: 'xxxx'
, accessToken: tokeny
, show : 15
, image_size: 'low_resolution'
, onComplete : function (photos, data) {
  insta_next_url = data.pagination.next_url
   }
   })

  $('button').on('click', function(){
   var 
  button = $(this)
   , text = button.text()

    if (button.text() != 'Loading...'){
   button.text('Loading...')
   insta_container.instagram({
      next_url : insta_next_url
    , show : 50
     , image_size: 'low_resolution'
    , onComplete : function(photos, data) {
      insta_next_url = data.pagination.next_url
      button.text(text)
    }
  })
  }        
 }) 
});
</script> 



    <div class="instagram"></div>
   <br>

  <button class="instamore">More</button><br><br>
```

Everything loads into the "instagram" div. From there, the images go into another div "instagram-placeholder".

Here is the CSS:

```
 .instagram {
 width:100%;
 }

 .instagram-placeholder {
 float:left;
 width:15%;
 height:15%;
 }

 .instagram-image {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
   border-style: none;
  }

  .instamore{
  width: 100%;
   color: #fbfbfb;
  font-style: italic;
  font: 30px Sans-Serif;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #3F3F3F;
   border-radius: 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   margin-right: 3px;
   margin-top:10px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
  cursor:pointer
   }
```

Comment: you should post a direct link to sample website to let guys debug it. A css margin:0 auto; on container seems what you want but it's quite impossible to say without be able to debug website

Comment: I was trying to inspect the images, and it too me longer than I'd like to admit to realize OP had provided a link to a screenshot. Anyway, ditch `float:left;` and go with `display:inline-block;`.

Comment: I have included the test page link in the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `width` does not include `border`.  So, your element with `width: 20%` and a 3px border is actually `20% + 6px` wide.  You can change this behavior with `box-sizing`:

```
.instagram-placeholder{
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    height:15%;
    border:3px double #999;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

This will make the `width` include the `border`.

Without the property, the 5th image wraps:

http://jsfiddle.net/dR4Vt/9

With it, it doesn't:

http://jsfiddle.net/dR4Vt/8

Note that this is IE8+ and does require the prefix for FF and earlier versions of some others.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Comment: a link to the live test page is available now

Comment: @user1449369 100% doesn't divide evenly by 15%.  Use something like 20% or 10% that does and it works.

Comment: Notably old IE already uses the border box model, and some newer IEs will switch to using it depending on the doctype: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200612/internet_explorer_and_the_css_box_model/

Comment: Ok, works great in firefox (ofcourse). IE still is showing a gap when using 20% image sizes with NO border. All thats in the placeholder is width and height. 10% the gap is ofcourse smaller. It still seems to not be utilizing the full 100%. Basically, with 20% its only showing 4 images before going to the next line.

Comment: CSS at my post is most current.

Comment: @user1449369 Which IE?  Seems fine in IE10.  You might try `font-size: 0`, though I didn't think that was needed when floating.

Comment: bah, was in IE7 standards. IE8 standards is fine